# Is there way to detect if user uses old monitor or new one with css or js?

Tags: javascript, css

Some elements of my new website are displayed very bad on my old monitor(I suppose it is caused by number of colors supported by monitor), but my new laptop displays these elements very well. I assume that some users also use old monitors but I don't want to change styles for all users, but only for those who uses old monitors.

I tried a lot of options, such as `color` and `color-gamot` in css `@media`, also `screen.colorDepth` in js. But these values are equal for my new laptop and old monitor.

So, is there way to detect if user uses old monitor and apply another styles for elements in such cases?

Comment: Nope. The maximum you can do is check the resolution.

Comment: you could try detecting pixel density: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio - not like anything official but generally newer screens use 2x pixel density

Comment: @KaiQing I've just tried it. It is 1.375 on both laptop and monitor(

Comment: It may be that your old monitor used to be just as vibrant as your laptop screen, but has faded over time. There's no way of programmatically determining that.

Comment: What do you mean from bad? Bad color?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I have element with shadows, these shadows are not visible at all, also I have element with #ededed color and white background, it is very hard to catch sight of this element

Comment: #ededed is a stabdard web color and all monitor can display it. It seems the problem is because of physical (hardware) contrast and brightbness and setting and is not detectable by programming

Comment: Such is the way it goes though. Why do you care is the bigger question? It seems that worrying about older monitors is about as fruitful as making sure a website looks good in IE5 or an iphone 3. Times change. If you're just curious then ok, but I wouldn't dedicate much time to this effort

Answer (score 1):

The [`screen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen) object will tell you just about everything you need..

```js
console.log(screen);
```

You could try this too for getting the pixel ratio.

```js
var e = document.createElement('div'), ppi;
e.style.width = '1in';
document.body.appendChild(e);
ppi = e.offsetWidth * devicePixelRatio;
document.body.removeChild(e);
console.log(`Your screen has ${ppi} pixels per square inch`);
```

Comment: `colorDepth` and `pixelDepth` are equal on both my laptop and monitor. If you suggest to use another properties please give some example how I can differ old monitor from new one